# How to use open3d (Registration ICP) to match orientation box with source box?

Tags: python, open3d

I tried to use `open3d==0.13.0` to match target orientation box `rx=45,ry=45,zr=45` in degree with source box with `transformation_init = np.asarray([[1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]])`, but the result still does not match with the source box.

```
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
import copy


points = []
for dim in range(3):
    for val in [0, 2]:
        face_points_dim = np.full((20, 20), val)
        face_points_other1, face_points_other2 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 2, 20), np.linspace(0, 2, 20))
        face_points = np.empty((20, 20, 3))
        face_points[:, :, dim] = face_points_dim
        face_points[:, :, (dim + 1) % 3] = face_points_other1
        face_points[:, :, (dim + 2) % 3] = face_points_other2
        points.append(face_points.reshape(-1, 3))
xyz = np.concatenate(points, axis=0)

pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz)
pcd.estimate_normals()
rotation = R.from_euler('xyz', [45, 45, 45], degrees=True)
rotated_xyz = rotation.apply(xyz)
target = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
target.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(rotated_xyz)
target.estimate_normals()
transformation_init = np.asarray([[1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]])
convergence_criteria = o3d.pipelines.registration.ICPConvergenceCriteria(max_iteration=2000, relative_fitness=1e-5, relative_rmse=1e-5)
reg_p2p = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_icp(
    pcd, target, 0.02, transformation_init,
    o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPlane(),
    convergence_criteria
)

print(reg_p2p)
print("Transformation is:")
print(reg_p2p.transformation)

final_rotation = reg_p2p.transformation[:3, :3]
final_translation = reg_p2p.transformation[:3, 3]
print("Final rotation is:")
print(final_rotation)
print("Final translation is:")
print(final_translation)


source_temp = copy.deepcopy(pcd)
source_temp.transform(transformation_init)

print("\nShowing initial matching")
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([source_temp, target],
                                  zoom=0.5,
                                  front=[0, 0, -1],
                                  lookat=[2, 2, 2],
                                  up=[0, 1, 0])


source_temp = copy.deepcopy(pcd)
source_temp.transform(reg_p2p.transformation)
print("\nShowing final matching")
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([source_temp, target],
                                  zoom=0.5,
                                  front=[0, 0, -1],
                                  lookat=[2, 2, 2],
                                  up=[0, 1, 0])
```

I also tried modified code where `max_iteration`, `relative_fitness`, and `relative_rmse` are set as required in `ICPConvergenceCriteria`

Answer (score 0):

This is a code update. If I use an threshold of 50 it works as expected and added Gaussian noise to the target.

```
import copy
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

def draw_registration_result(source, target, transformation, zoom=1.5):
    source_temp = copy.deepcopy(source)
    target_temp = copy.deepcopy(target)
    source_temp.paint_uniform_color([0, 0, 1])
    target_temp.paint_uniform_color([0, 1, 0])

    print("\nShowing initial matching")
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([source_temp, target_temp],
                                    zoom=zoom,
                                    front=[0.9288, -0.2951, -0.2242],
                                    lookat=[0, 1, 1],
                                    up=[0, 0, 1])

    print("\nShowing final matching")
    source_temp.transform(transformation)
    coord_frame = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_coordinate_frame()
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([source_temp, target_temp, coord_frame],
                                  zoom=zoom,
                                  front=[0.9288, -0.2951, -0.2242],
                                  lookat=[0, 1, 1],
                                  up=[0, 0, 1])
    
def create_box(noise_std_dev=0.0):
    points = []
    for dim in range(3):
        for val in [0, 2]:
            face_points_dim = np.full((20, 20), val)
            face_points_other1, face_points_other2 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 2, 20), np.linspace(0, 2, 20))
            face_points = np.empty((20, 20, 3))
            face_points[:, :, dim] = face_points_dim
            face_points[:, :, (dim + 1) % 3] = face_points_other1
            face_points[:, :, (dim + 2) % 3] = face_points_other2
            points.append(face_points.reshape(-1, 3))
    xyz = np.concatenate(points, axis=0)
    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz)
    pcd.estimate_normals()
    rotation = R.from_euler('xyz', [45, 0, 0], degrees=True)
    rotated_xyz = rotation.apply(xyz)
    # Add Gaussian noise to the target
    # Standard deviation of the noise. You can adjust this value.
    noise = np.random.normal(0, noise_std_dev, rotated_xyz.shape)
    noisy_rotated_xyz = rotated_xyz + noise
    target = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    target.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(noisy_rotated_xyz)
    target.estimate_normals()
    transformation_init = np.asarray([[1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]])
    return pcd, target, transformation_init

def extract_euler_from_matrix(transformation_matrix):
    x, y, z = transformation_matrix[:3, 3]
    rotation_matrix = transformation_matrix[:3, :3]
    rx = np.degrees(np.arctan2(rotation_matrix[2, 1], rotation_matrix[2, 2]))
    ry = np.degrees(-np.arctan2(rotation_matrix[2, 0], np.sqrt(rotation_matrix[2, 1]**2 + rotation_matrix[2, 2]**2)))
    rz = np.degrees(np.arctan2(rotation_matrix[1, 0], rotation_matrix[0, 0]))
    return x, y, z, rx, ry, rz


def registration_icp(pcd, target, transformation_init):
    convergence_criteria = o3d.pipelines.registration.ICPConvergenceCriteria(max_iteration=2000, 
                                                                             relative_fitness=1e-5, 
                                                                             relative_rmse=1e-5)
    thr = 50.0
    reg_p2p = o3d.pipelines.registration.registration_icp(
        pcd, target, thr, transformation_init,
        o3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPlane(),
        convergence_criteria
    )

    '''
    Transformation matrix.
    '''
    print("Transformation is:")
    print(reg_p2p.transformation)
    final_rotation = reg_p2p.transformation[:3, :3]
    final_translation = reg_p2p.transformation[:3, 3]
    print(final_rotation)
    print("Final translation is:")
    print(final_translation)
    x, y, z, rx, ry, rz = extract_euler_from_matrix(transformation_matrix=reg_p2p.transformation)
    print(f"x:{x}, y:{y}, z:{z}, rx:{rx}, ry:{ry}, rz:{rz}")
    '''
    Transformation matrix.
    '''

    source_temp = copy.deepcopy(pcd)
    source_temp.transform(transformation_init)
    draw_registration_result(source=source_temp,target=target,transformation=reg_p2p.transformation)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pcd, target, transformation_init = create_box(noise_std_dev=0.07)
    registration_icp(pcd=pcd, target=target, transformation_init=transformation_init)
```

```
Transformation is:
[[ 9.99987173e-01  1.57532059e-03 -4.81376216e-03  4.57822184e-03]
 [-4.50522269e-03  7.10944598e-01 -7.03233590e-01  2.93253628e-04]
 [ 2.31449985e-03  7.03246256e-01  7.10942576e-01  1.86811886e-03]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00]]
[[ 0.99998717  0.00157532 -0.00481376]
 [-0.00450522  0.7109446  -0.70323359]
 [ 0.0023145   0.70324626  0.71094258]]
Final translation is:
[0.00457822 0.00029325 0.00186812]
Extract euler:
x:0.00457822183653805, y:0.0002932536277546905, z:0.0018681188593605135, rx:44.68818712412947, ry:-0.13261119149981235, rz:-0.25813181050792067
```

[Showing initial matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaDqO.png)
[Showing final matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uJm4.png)

Answer (score 0):

ICP is suitable when a good initial approximation for the transformation is known and is good because the data may be incomplete or noisy and the relationships between points are unknown. In our case, the order of the points is preserved under the transformation we want to find. Thus, we can immediately use the method of determining the transformation between points ([open3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint.html)). This method is called the [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm#:%7E:text=The%20Kabsch%20algorithm%2C%20also%20known,two%20paired%20sets%20of%20points.) and is implemented in the Eigen library ([umeyama.h](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/Umeyama_8h_source.html)). As an alternative, you can use the method from the following repository [github/MIT-SPARK/TEASER-plusplus](https://github.com/MIT-SPARK/TEASER-plusplus).

Here is the code using the correct method

```
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
import copy

points = []
for dim in range(3):
    for val in [0, 2]:
        face_points_dim = np.full((20, 20), val)
        face_points_other1, face_points_other2 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 2, 20), np.linspace(0, 2, 20))
        face_points = np.empty((20, 20, 3))
        face_points[:, :, dim] = face_points_dim
        face_points[:, :, (dim + 1) % 3] = face_points_other1
        face_points[:, :, (dim + 2) % 3] = face_points_other2
        points.append(face_points.reshape(-1, 3))
xyz = np.concatenate(points, axis=0)

pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz)
# pcd.estimate_normals() # we don't need normals
rotation = R.from_euler('xyz', [45, 45, 45], degrees=True)
rotated_xyz = rotation.apply(xyz)
target = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
target.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(rotated_xyz)
# target.estimate_normals()

estimation_method = open3d.pipelines.registration.TransformationEstimationPointToPoint()
correspondences = open3d.utility.Vector2iVector(np.tile(np.arange(len(target.points)), reps=(2, 1)).T)
transformation = estimation_method.compute_transformation(source=pcd, target=target, corres=correspondences)

source_in_target = copy.deepcopy(pcd).transform(transformation)
source_in_target.paint_uniform_color([1., 0., 0.])
target.paint_uniform_color([0., 1., 0.])

error = np.linalg.norm(np.asarray(source_in_target.points) - np.asarray(target.points), axis=-1).max()
print(f"Max geometric error between points from source and target {error:.2f}")

# we translate source by small amount to show that is different from target
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([source_in_target.translate([0.01, 0., 0.]), target])
```